# perl regex escape characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have heard perl is a good language at doing regex but i am a bit confused at the characters that requires escaping

I tested the code on http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and got the result I want

```
//home/dev/abc/code/hello/world.cpp#1
//home/dev/((.*?)/[^/]+).*#

Match   $1  $2
//home/dev/abc/code/hello/world.cpp#    abc/code    abc
```

However, I am not quite sure how do i translate this to perl code

I tried,

```
\/\/home\/dev\/\(\(\.\*\?\)\/\[\^\/\]\+\)\.\*\#
```

and

```
\/\/home\/dev\/((.*?)\/[^\/]+).*\#
```

and both failed

Don't you think the escaping makes the regex very unreadable? Am i using something wrong?

Comment: quotemeta is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose use `!` instead of `/` to surround your regular expression so that you don't have to escape the `/`.

```
m!//home/dev/((.*?)/[^/]+).*#!
```

should work. Here's it in action: http://ideone.com/TDrBG

Comment: It's worth adding to this that it is not just `!`  that can be used. you can use any almost any character you want. just as long as you have two or three of them with either `m` or `s`.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using perl you don't have to use `/` as the regex delimiter if you preceed the delimiter with "m" for the matching operator, or "s" for the substitution operator (e.g. you can use `#` or `!` or even any balanced parentheses/brackets: `s[this][that]`), and then you don't have to escape `/`. You can also use the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function or `\Q`…`\E` regex [escape sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences) that automatically escape any metacharacters.

Comment: You can even use alphanumerics, preceded by whitespace: `print "m"=~m ama;`.  But don't use ? or ' unless you want the alternative behaviors those cause.