# How to match the following in PERL?

Tags: php, regex, perl, find, match

My **$string** is

> "Eine Streitbeilegung i.S.e. Konfliktl&#x00F6;sung kann auch durch
>   Verlagerung auf au&#x00DF;ergerichtliche “Stellen”
>   erfolgen. Sie kann hierbei vom Gesetz f&#x00FC;r bestimmte
>   Streitigkeiten obligatorisch angeordnet werden, z. B. &#x00A7; 15a
>   EGZPO, so dass ein Schlichtungsverfahren einem gerichtlichen
>   Rechtsstreit zwingend vorausgehen muss. In anderen F&#x00E4;llen
>   besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen (z. B. Schlichtungsgesetze der
>   Bundesl&#x00E4;nder) die M&#x00F6;glichkeit, in bestimmten
>   Streitf&#x00E4;llen freiwillig ein &#x201C;Schiedsverfahren&#x201D;
>   durchzuf&#x00FC;hren, also zu w&#x00E4;hlen, ob direkt ein
>   gerichtliches Verfahren angestrengt oder zun&#x00E4;chst eine
>   au&#x00DF;ergerichtliche Streitschlichtung durchgef&#x00FC;hrt wird.
>   Weiterhin kann zur Erledigung b&#x00FC;rgerlich-rechtlicher
>   Streitigkeiten durch Vertrag ein Schiedsgerichtsverfahren gem.
>   &#x00A7;&#x00A7; 1025 ff. ZPO vereinbart werden. Daneben existieren
>   eine Vielzahl privater G&#x00FC;te-, Schieds- und Schlichtungsstellen,
>   deren Anrufung freiwillig ist. Diese Instrumente der Streitbeilegung
>   bestehen au&#x00DF;erhalb der o.g. Recht-Sprechung bzw. des
>   gesetzlichen Richters und sind damit &#x201C;alternativ&#x201D; zu
>   gerichtlicher Streitbeilegung w&#x00E4;hlbar."\

I want to match the following string in above paragraph

**$matchLines:**

> besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen (z. B. Schlichtungsgesetze der
>   Bundesl&#x00E4;nder)

I cant find this string but it is present in the above content,

I tried :

```
while ($string=~m/($matchLines)/gi) {
    print $string;
}
```

anybody please give any ideas

Thanks in advance
Vimal

Comment: Can you tell us what the value of `$matchLines` is?

Comment: value is "besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen (z. B. Schlichtungsgesetze der Bundesl&#x00E4;nder)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `index` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Eine Streitbeilegung i.S.e. Konfliktl&#x00F6;sung kann auch durch Verlagerung auf au&#x00DF;ergerichtliche “Stellen” erfolgen. Sie kann hierbei vom Gesetz f&#x00FC;r bestimmte Streitigkeiten obligatorisch angeordnet werden, z. B. &#x00A7; 15a EGZPO, so dass ein Schlichtungsverfahren einem gerichtlichen Rechtsstreit zwingend vorausgehen muss. In anderen F&#x00E4;llen besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen (z. B. Schlichtungsgesetze der Bundesl&#x00E4;nder) die M&#x00F6;glichkeit, in bestimmten Streitf&#x00E4;llen freiwillig ein &#x201C;Schiedsverfahren&#x201D; durchzuf&#x00FC;hren, also zu w&#x00E4;hlen, ob direkt ein gerichtliches Verfahren angestrengt oder zun&#x00E4;chst eine au&#x00DF;ergerichtliche Streitschlichtung durchgef&#x00FC;hrt wird. Weiterhin kann zur Erledigung b&#x00FC;rgerlich-rechtlicher Streitigkeiten durch Vertrag ein Schiedsgerichtsverfahren gem. &#x00A7;&#x00A7; 1025 ff. ZPO vereinbart werden. Daneben existieren eine Vielzahl privater G&#x00FC;te-, Schieds- und Schlichtungsstellen, deren Anrufung freiwillig ist. Diese Instrumente der Streitbeilegung bestehen au&#x00DF;erhalb der o.g. Recht-Sprechung bzw. des gesetzlichen Richters und sind damit &#x201C;alternativ&#x201D; zu gerichtlicher Streitbeilegung w&#x00E4;hlbar.';

my $matchLines = 'besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen (z. B. Schlichtungsgesetze der Bundesl&#x00E4;nder)';

print "$matchLines\n" if index($string, $matchLines)>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match it as a `regex` straightaway since you will have to escape the `()` and the `.` in a regex. Therefore, you should either use `index` to check if substring exists in string or use `substr`.

If you want to use regex, it would have to look like this to match:

`besteht aufgrund von Landesgesetzen \(z\. B\. Schlichtungsgesetze der Bundesl&#x00E4;nder\)`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jK2fF5

Comment: Thanks sshashank I tried with quotemeta and its working fine now !

Answer (score 0):

Check answer [perl regex escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550523/perl-regex-escape-characters) about [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: I tried with quotemeta and its working fine now !  thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can test match or no bu using [RegexTester]:http://ccmpp.com/Regex/regex%20tester.htm